# How to integrate Jmeter test results on to Sonarqube?

Tags: jmeter, sonarqube, jmeter-plugins

Since the Jmeter plugin is deprecated now, how to post results on to Sonarqube.  Kindly quide us in integrating jmeter results with Sonarqube.

Answer (score 0):

You can integrate Jenkins with both Sonarqube and [JMeter](https://wiki.jenkins.io/plugins/servlet/mobile?contentId=104759410#content/view/104759410) scripts so results from JMeter will be sent to Sonarqube.
 You can see live project example, [JMeter build](https://builds.apache.org/job/JMeter-trunk/) execute both in Jenkins.